# How can one set Electrum as default bitcoin uri handler?

Tags: macos, url, links

[Bitcoin links](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0021.mediawiki) are formatted beginning with `bitcoin:` followed by a bitcoin address and optionally more information.

On my Mac, the Bitcoin-QT program is the default one to open when I click such links. I wish to change it to the Electrum client.

My question is - where in MacOS are the uri handlers defined? How can I change this to open my program of choice?